# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception'

Tags: php

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /home/u569177978/public_html/app_data/mysqldao.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /home/u569177978/public_html/app_data/userRegister.php(36): MySQLDao->registerUser('wesdfed', 'wefrd') #1 {main} thrown in /home/u569177978/public_html/app_data/mysqldao.php on line 68
```

from the following script: http://pastebin.com/QYYQMTEV

Yes, I have looked up this problem and none of those solutions have worked for me. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mysqli::prepare() returns `false` if the provided SQL is invalid. I would double-check your SQL.

Comment: Why would return returning false generate an exception? I'd guess this was more likely being caused by the explicit exception being raised in openConnection that's never actually handled anywhere.

Comment: @andrewsi Because an Exception is thrown on line 68 if the statement evaluates to `false`.